# Как удалить в строке пробелы исключая из проверки подстроки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Строка имеет вид: "IF ( fd1="","Not found",fd1 )"
Возможно ли с помощью регулярного выражения (или другим способом) удалить все пробелы в строке, но исключить пробелы в подстроке "Not found" ? Подстрок может быть несколько с различным текстом.
Я пробовал использовать вариант:

```
str.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Но в этом случае в подстроке также удаляются пробелы.

Comment: _Подстрок может быть несколько с различным текстом._ а в этих подстроках необходимо оставлять пробелы? Если так, то при условии, что ваша строка всегда четко имеет вид _IF ( fd1="","Not found",fd1 )_ можете убирать пробелы вокруг привычных знаков не задевая текст. `str.replaceAll(", ", ","); str.replaceAll(" ( ", "("); str.replaceAll(" )", ")");` . Приведите больше примеров ваших строк и желаемый результат от них. Постарайтесь охватить все случаи.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/KZur2K/1 - попробуйте что-нибудь такое, замена пробелов выполняется вне границ кавычек: `(\"[^\"]*?\")|\h`

Comment: @ipatev_nn , Ваш вариант отлично подходит. Итог `str.replaceAll("(\"[^\"]*?\")|\h", "$1");`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте шаблон с негативными просмотрами назад и вперед `(?<!Not)\\s(?!found)`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "IF ( fd1=\"\",\"Not found\",fd1 )";
        text = text.replaceAll("(?<!Not)\\s(?!found)", "");
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

```
IF(fd1="","Not found",fd1)
```

Более сложная версия для обработки случаев вида `IF ( fd1="","Not around",fd1 )`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] texts = {"IF ( fd1=\"\",\"Not found\",fd1 )",
                          "IF ( fd1=\"\",\"Not around\",fd1 )",
                          "IF ( fd1=\"\",\"Yes found\",fd1 )",
                          "IF ( fd1=\"\",\"Blood hound\",fd1 )"};
        for (String t : texts)
            System.out.println(t.replaceAll("(?<!Not)\\s+(?!found)|(?<!Not)\\s+(?=found)|(?<=Not)\\s+(?!found)", ""));
    }
}
```

```
IF(fd1="","Not found",fd1)
IF(fd1="","Notaround",fd1)
IF(fd1="","Yesfound",fd1)
IF(fd1="","Bloodhound",fd1)
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Данный вариант не подойдет, т.к. в подстроке может быть различный текст, у Вас же привязывается к содержимому подстроки.

Comment: @EtcOS я делал вариант до уточнения "Подстрок может быть несколько с различным текстом"